# How can I achieve WYSIWYG in NetBeans GUI Builder?

Tags: java, netbeans, wysiwyg, gui-builder, absolutelayout

I've spent many fruitless hours trying to create what I consider to be a very simple GUI.  One thing that makes it simple is that *I don't even expect it to be resizeable*.  I want it to display just the way I've laid it out.  Simple as that.

There's a JFrame containing two Jpanels of equal width, one above the other.  I've got the JPanels behaving themselves finally, and I can slide them around without their enclosed components mysteriously shifting.

But I can't for the life of me get the JFrame to nicely enclose the JPanels.  I'm attaching a screen shot showing the layout and the inspector[image], and another showing how it previews [image]

(Notice that it's chopping off the bottom edge.)

Is there any way to work in a "WYSIWYG mode" in the GUI builder?  I don't care about (in fact, I dread) resizeability, at all at this point.  I would have thought Absolute Layout would be the right choice for this, but there's still something wrong.  (I need an *elementary* solution, folks -- please don't suggest GridBagLayout!! ;)

EDIT: By restoring some defaults, mainly for MaximumSize, to the JFrame, I got rid of the clipping problem.  The right edge was still off by one pixel, and I managed to find which of five (five!) width properties was controlling that.  (bounds, max size, min size, preferred size, and width - changing min size fixed that.)

I've already found that you can't completely avoid tweaking properties (e.g. to override "snapping" and achieve pixel-precise positioning).  I clearly made trouble for myself at some point by playing with some properties I shouldn't have.  The question remains: for non-resizable, WYSIWYG GUI design, is Absolute Layout a reliable choice; *and*, what properties should I avoid editing?

Answer (score 1):

Is the JFrame showing any better when you actually run than  preview? I think this is an OS X specific NB behavior. I did not see this in Win32. For now, you may try adding a JLabel ( spaces as the text content) at the bottom to make sure that space is drawn when the actual JFrame runs.

Comment: The rendering at runtime is identical to the preview.  And adding a JLabel at the bottom didn't change anything - the JFrame's bottom edge still clips it off.